# Terraform Apply Throws Error with Azure RM 3.0 and Trying to Provision an App Gateway with User Assigned Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

[image]I am stuck here with a cyclical issue.

I had an Application Gateway which i provisioned using Azure RM 2.0 provider in Terraform. But i wanted to upgrade to AzureRm Version 3.0 and Terraform complained that it will be destroying the Public IP

But it wasn't able to destroy the public IP because it was associated to my App Gateway

So i had no other option but to delete the App Gateway from the portal and re run Terraform again

I also wanted Terraform to read the certificates from a Key Vault which is in another Subscription

So i created a "User Assigned Managed Identity" and assigned it to the App Gateway and also gave the "User Assigned Identity" , "Certificate Officer" RBAC role in the KV

But then when i tried to run Terraform Plan and Apply i got the below error :

```
Error: waiting for create of Application Gateway: (Name "agw-xxx-dev-cus-ab83" / Resource Group "rg-xxxx-dev-cus-7cda"): Code="ApplicationGatewayKeyVaultSecretException" Message="Problem occured while accessing and validating KeyVault Secrets associated with Application Gateway '/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xx/resourceGroups/rg-xxxx-dev-cus-7cda/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/agw-xxx-dev-cus-ab83'. See details below:" Details=[{"code":"0","message":"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"},{"code":"0","message":"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"},{"code":"0","message":"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"},{"code":"0","message":"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"},{"code":"0","message":"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"}]
│ 
│   with azurerm_application_gateway.application_gateway,
│   on resources.appgw.tf line 434, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "application_gateway":
│  434: resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "application_gateway" {
```

But when i went to the App Gateway in Azure Portal it was showing in red as "Failed"

When i went to Listeners --> Listeners TLS Certificates (Preview), i was able to see all the KV references in there under Key Vault ID where my certs were loaded.

So that means the App Gateway was able to talk to my KV and retrieve the Certs successfully, but inspite of that it was throwing that error above

Now if i deleted the App GW completely and re-ran Terraform again, i got the below error :

```
A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/rg-xxxx-dev-cus-c02f/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/agw-xxxx-dev-cus-45a0" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_application_gateway" for more information.
│ 
│   with azurerm_application_gateway.application_gateway,
│   on resources.appgw.tf line 434, in resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "application_gateway":
│  434: resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "application_gateway" {
```

Is this some kind of a bug in the provider, i am facing this issue after i upgraded to AzureRm 3.0 and not able to create the App GW and link KVs properly to read certs from them

Answer (score 0):

Use sleep time to create App gateway to give time for the role or access  policies to be effective:

```
 resource "time_sleep" "sleeptime" {
      depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault.mykeyvault]
      create_duration = "60s"
    }
```

The below error possibly occurred if have deleted the app gateway configuration In portal but still exists in state.

```
`A resource with the ID "<resourceId of appgw>" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_application_gateway" for more information`.
```

Do terraform import to match state file with the ID in the error.
***`Terraform import azurerm_application_gateway.example   <resourceIdOf the error>`*** as certificate might be still attached to Application gateway.

or

execute  **`terraform destroy`**  to clear the state.

Code:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "mykeyvault" {
  name                       = "myexamplekv"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name = "standard"
  access_policy {
    object_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
    tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

    certificate_permissions = [
      "Create",
      "Delete",
      "DeleteIssuers",
      "Get",
      "GetIssuers",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "ListIssuers",
      "ManageContacts",
      "ManageIssuers",
      "Purge",
      "SetIssuers",
      "Update"
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Create",
      "Decrypt",
      "Delete",
      "Encrypt",
      "Get",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Sign",
      "UnwrapKey",
      "Update",
      "Verify",
      "WrapKey"
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Delete",
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Restore",
      "Restore",
      "Set"
    ]
  }

  access_policy {
    object_id    = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.base.principal_id
    tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

    secret_permissions = [
      "Get"
    ]
  }
}

output "secret_identifier" {
  value = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.secret_id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "example" {
  name         = "mynewgenereatedcert"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.mykeyvault.id

  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "Self"
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = true
    }

    lifetime_action {
      action {
        action_type = "AutoRenew"
      }

      trigger {
        days_before_expiry = 30
      }
    }

    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }

    x509_certificate_properties {
      extended_key_usage = ["1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"]

      key_usage = [
        "cRLSign",
        "dataEncipherment",
        "digitalSignature",
        "keyAgreement",
        "keyCertSign",
        "keyEncipherment",
      ]

      subject_alternative_names {
        dns_names = ["domain.hello.world"]
      }

      subject            = "CN=hello-world"
      validity_in_months = 12
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
 ...
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "frontend" {
 ...
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "backend" {
  ....
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  ....
}

.
locals {
  frontend_port_name             = "exm-feport"
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "exm-feip"
  backend_address_pool_name      = "exm-beap" 
  http_setting_name              = "exm-be-htst"
  listener_name                  = "exm-httplstn"
  request_routing_rule_name      = "exm-rqrt"
  redirect_configuration_name    = "exm-rdrcfg"

}




resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "myappgw" {
  name                = "kavyaappgateway"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location

  sku {
    name     = "Standard_v2"
    tier     = "Standard_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }

  gateway_ip_configuration {
    ...
  }

  frontend_port {
    ...
  }

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    ...
  }

  backend_address_pool {
    name = local.backend_address_pool_name
  }

  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = local.http_setting_name
    ....
  }

  http_listener {
    name                           = local.listener_name
    ....
    protocol                       = "Https"
    ssl_certificate_name = "app_listener"
  }

  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.useraid.id]
  }

  ssl_certificate {
    name = "app_listener"
    key_vault_secret_id = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.secret_id
  }

  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = local.request_routing_rule_name
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = local.listener_name
    backend_address_pool_name  = local.backend_address_pool_name
    backend_http_settings_name = local.http_setting_name
  }

  depends_on = [time_sleep.sleeptime]
}
```

**`terraform apply`** to run the code successfully.

---

ApplicationGatewayKeyVaultSecretException:

```
Error:  Code="ApplicationGatewayKeyVaultSecretException" Message="Problem occured while accessing and validating KeyVault Secrets associated with Application Gateway '<appgw resourceid>'.
```

***Check if secret or certificate is`disabled`  , as version change can update the certificate .***

Enable the certificate in portal if it is in disabled state.

[image]